# XSL: create an Array from a Delimited String

Tags: arrays, xslt, xpath, splice

I have a string name "string Variable" = 'hello, hello, good Evening, good evening'.
I want to create an array on which I can do a foreach with the values divided by commas.

tnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT and XPath don't have an array data type unless you happen to use XPath 3.1 with XSLT 3. However in XSLT and XPath since version 2 there is a `tokenize` function you can use with e.g. `tokenize('hello, hello, good Evening, good evening', ',\s*')` to get a sequence of strings you can then process like any other sequence, for instance with a `for-each`.